# css problem with make text in the right

Tags: css, css-float

i have this

```
<li><a href="#" >title</a> <span style='text-align:right;'>(0)</span></li>
```

its not working
and this

```
<li><a href="#" >title</a> <span style='float:right;'>(0)</span></li>
```

its go to the down line (not working)

its appear like that

```
|title (0)     |
```

i want it

```
|title      (0)|
```

Comment: A CSS question is off topic... really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is likely a more elegant solution to do this but this should work:

```
<li style="position:relative">
    <a href="#">title</a> <span style="position:absolute; right:0;">(0)</span>
</li>
```

You may want to add padding-right to the li to account for the space used by the span so that the link text and the span don't overlap.